# nmap & arp cache behaviour

Tags: nmap, arp

Why does the target of a nmap scan, where the target does not exist get entered into the arp cache?

```
nmap -v -P0 -sT  192.168.1.103
```

That scan always shows "host up".

This behaviour made me go crazy >:(

Edit: The arp cache is as shown in the correct answer. Thanks guys!

Comment: Please show the corresponding arp entry (edit the question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shows "host up" because you told nmap to assume the host is up—that's what `-P0` (or its newer equivalent `-Pn`) does.

Presumably it shows up in the arp cache like this:

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.1.103                    (incomplete)                              eth0
```

which means the kernel sent out an ARP request, but hasn't received a reply. That happened because you told the kernel to send a packet (well, quite a few packets, actually) to the host.